# Java regex for a specific phone number format

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex java pattern to match the following string:

```
 [Phone Number]= 1234567890
```

Here:
 The regex should look for hardcoded string of `"[Phone Number]=`" followed by space or not, and followed by
 any numbers of digits.

That means it should match:

```
[Phone Number]= 123456 and
[Phone Number]=1234567890
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, something like:

```
String pattern = "\\[Phone Number\\]= ?\\d+";
```

- The backslashes are doubled just because of Java string literal syntax
- The square brackets are escaped to avoid them being used to group a set of characters
- The `?` means zero or one space
- The `\d+` (after unescaping) means "at least one digit"

Answer (score 2):

What are your rules for a phone number?
Simply a list of digits is rarely a valid phone number format.

A simple search can find you the regexps for specific countries (I'll provide a specific one if you can tell us which one you need).